# PFQuery with NSPredicate and Pointer. Can they go together?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nspredicate

I have a class defined in Parse.com that has a Pointer "inviteUser" (that points to _User) and an Array column (an array of Strings)

What I am basically trying to find out is if there is a record in that table that points to that _User and has the a given String inside that Array.

What I have done so far is:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN theArray", myStringValue)
let query = PFQuery(className: "InviteClass", predicate: pred)
query.includeKey("inviteUser")
query.whereKey("inviteUser", equalTo:parseUser!["partnerUser"])
```

This is returning empty, although I am positive it should not. It's definitely something wrong I am doing. I am not sure if I can use NSPredicate and the whereKey() together.

I tested the whereKey alone, without the NSPredicate, and I get results. So I know that bit works.

I have also tested the NSPredicate alone, commenting out the two lines after the `let query` statement. That returned empty.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `query.whereKey("theArray", equalTo: myStringValue)` ? that should be equivalent to the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Check this predicate:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "theArray CONTAINS %@", myStringValue)
```

I don't know CONTAINS is supported by Parse or not, but it might help you to find the problem. If it's not working, you can try below code:

```
query.whereKey("theArray", containsString: myStringValue)
```